# PHP : sorting on ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, sorting

I have a page **search.php** where user search and search results shown on **search_records.php**.

On **search_records.php** Either user can search for new OR can sort the results, using a drop down ( see image below )

[image: Search Record page]

**current process :** Whenever user choose a value from drop down, we send ajax request to the server and fetch same data with extra **ORDER BY** clause and then display the data.

**change in process :** we can do the same using some PHP array function, when a user choose any value from drop down then we append `?sort=whatever` in current URL and then according to `$_GET['sort']`, we'll re arrange the array of search results.

But I couldn't succeed so far as I tried  below 2 way.

**1)With HTML/PHP**

```
<select id="sortMyData">
        <option value="asc"><a href="searchrecords.php?sort=asc">Low to high price</option>
        <option value="asc"><a href="searchrecords.php?sort=desc">High ti low price</option>
        <option value="asc"><a href="searchrecords.php?sort=age">Younger to older</option>
</select>
```

but I was surprised to know that `<a>` doesn't work inside `<option>` or am I doing something wrong here?

**2)With jQuery**

```
   <select id="sortMyData">
      <option value="asc">Price: Low to High</option>
      <option value="desc">Price: High to Low </option>
      <option value="age">Younger to older</option>
   </select>

 $('#sortMyData').change(function(e){
    var locAppend = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),
    alert("Redirecting to: " + locSnip + locAppend);
    window.location ='searchrecords.php?sort='+locAppend ;
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery checkout the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin. It handles all of the sorting and paging you could ever want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<select id="sortMyData" name="sortMyData">
    <option value="asc">Low to high price</option>
    <option value="desc">High ti low price</option>
    <option value="age">Younger to older</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php
// form receiver 
    if (isset($_POST['sortMyData']))
    {
        switch($_POST['sortMyData'])
        {
            case 'asc': header("Location : http://path/to/searchrecords.php?sort=asc");
                        break;
            case 'desc': header("Location : http://path/to/searchrecords.php?sort=desc");
                        break;
            case 'age': header("Location : http://path/to/searchrecords.php?sort=age");
                        break;

        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: by this page loaded again and then data lost